# Alternate of window.location.origin in PHP

Tags: php, html, window.location

I want to redirect the domain1.com/abc to domain2.com/abc without changing /abc it should be the same but only domain should change. I mean after / everything should be same only the domain before / should be changed to domain2.  Like I do using script:-

```
<script>
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin,&quot;https://www.domain2.com&quot;) 
</script>

<script>
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin,&quot;https://www.domain2.com&quot;) 
</script>
```

Comment: Trying this: <?php
<script type="text/javascript">
     if (window.location.href = "https://www.domain1.com") {
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin,"https://www.domain2.com") 
 }

</script>
?>

But it doesn't work

Comment: that is simple redirect, I want only domain change not the whole link after "/"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Location` HTTP header.

Build the header value with a requested domain and a value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value:

```
<?php

$domain = 'http://domain2.com';
$location = $domain . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header('Location: ' . $location);
```

Comment: not working, not chaging domain1

Comment: you're doing something wrong then. show what you're doing, noone can help you with "not working".